# How to display images in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

After doing

```
HtmlElementCollection es = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
HtmlElement ele = es[5];
ele.InvokeMember("Click");
....
```

after click webrowser1 do not display google verification image, but after webbrowser1 refresh (F5) display

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in VS2010 webbrowser works correctly